# What type of Fiber network cable is this? Says 300m 10g om3

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, cable

I have some fiber cable I have to run in a building for someone.  There was a guy who know all about this and was going to order the cable then I would help him put it in.  He has just disappeared.  Anyways, I need to order the cable and someone else will help me install it.  Pulled through conduit 20 feet then 20 feet of attack then outside on awning for 40 feet then back to an attic for 20 feet.  So, a cable that is pulled through a similar location in the building says.

Optical cable - 300m/10g OM3 Optical Fiber OFNP E319478 (UL)

I take it OFNP means

"OFNP Cables:
OFNP stands for Optical Fiber Nonconductive Plenum. OFNP cables have fire-resistance and low smoke production characteristics. They can be installed in ducts, plenums and other spaces used for building airflow. This is the highest fire rating fiber cable and no other cable types can be used as substitutes."

Do you know what type of plugs these are on the fiber cable?  it says F on the switch 9F 10F.

I just found this.  Multipair black and 500 feet.  Should be good for outdoor.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/500-Foot-6-Fiber-Optic-Cable-50-125-m-Outdoor-Plenum-Multimode-10G-OFNP-OM2/332486486128?hash=item4d69bd2870:g:~6cAAOSwk1haMH8l

Will this cable work?  Or is there something else we should get?

Raw cable only so we would have to pay someone to add the ends but that is fine.  What should it cost to pay someone to install the same type ends that are plugged into 9F.  Just a ball park price so we do not get ripped off when we are looking for someone.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "What should it cost to pay someone to install the same type ends that are plugged into 9F. Just a ballpark price so we do not get ripped off when we are looking for someone." - This question is entirely out of scope here at Superuser.  How much it will cost depends on the number of people in the area with the knowledge.  We cannot predict market prices in your area.

Answer (score 1):

That cable will work fine. It is a multi-mode fiber used for short runs. Specifically, the OM3 standard means that you can run that cable a max of 300 meters (950 ft~) without a repeater and still retain 10gbps speeds. The connectors there look like [LC connectors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WenX8.jpg).

As far as price, a common practice nowadays, because of termination prices, is to buy a prefabricated cable and then have it pulled. [Something like this is more cost effective for one pull](http://www.lanshack.com/2-Strand-CustomLine-Indoor-Outdoor-Multimode-10-GIG-50125-OM3-Multimode-Fiber-Whips-Assembly-P7072.aspx) YOu would just need a 2 strand om3 pull with LC ends.

Comment: I do not thing the ends will make it trough the conduit.

Comment: Actually now that I look at http://www.lanshack.com/2-Strand-CustomLine-Indoor-Outdoor-Multimode-10-GIG-50125-OM3-Multimode-Fiber-Whips-Assembly-P7072.aspx again I looks pretty heavy duty and probably could go through the conduit.  The only thing is I do not know the length of the cable needed.  I can pull a robe through the entire run and measure.  I was hoping to avoid that cause that is the same amount of work as the install.  But i think that may be what we need to do.

Comment: Why is this answer the complete opposite of Tony's answer?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: You don't just PULL fiber through conduits and such. You have to be careful not to pull too hard. And fiber gets damaged when bend to much when going around corners.
When going outdoors you need properly protected cable, especially UV protection is really important.
For cables that are part of the infra-structure you use so-called plenum cable.
The link you found is outdoor cable, but the wrong type. It is OM2 and the blue cable you've got is OM3. For distances under 1000 feet, using 1 Gigabit connections, you can use either type without issues, but you should NOT mix the 2 types. If you are running 10 Gigabit connections you really need the OM3 type.
Next thing to consider is how many strands of fiber you need in your plenum cable. A single link (1 connector) has 2 strands. Plenum cables run from 2 to as much as 48 strands in a single cable. More strands is more expensive.
Plenum cable (indoor or outdoor ) is normally NOT terminated in connectors. Both ends of the cable are terminated in a patch-panel. You use short fiber patch-cables with connector at each end to make the connection from patch-panel to switch.
The connectors you've got on the existing cables are so-called "LC" connectors.
No idea what it would cost. I always buy my patch-cables pre-made and attaching the plenum cable to a patch-panel is part of the cost of installing the plenum cable which I leave to a specialist cable outfit. They install the plenum cables and patch-panels and test them to make sure they are ok.

TL:DR
Fiber can be done by the hobbyist, but most people should hire a professional.

Comment: @grawity Oops. My bad. I thought I had actually removed that before posting.

Comment: Where can I get the Plenum om3 500ft?  We are going to pay someone to do the ends.  We just need a single cable (in and out).  I just saw the 6/3 pairs connector one and it was cheep.  It would not hurt to have more but we would only terminate one of each side.

Comment: Multi-mode is plastic, and really easy to terminate. The professionals you speak of just glue the strands to the LC and buff the ends.

Comment: Well, they also know what specific kind of glue to use; they know how to prepare the ends to avoid signal loss; they know how to test the finished assembly (and the whole cable in case it had broken elsewhere); and they have tools for all those things.

Comment: @grawity Exactly that. Take e.g. a cable-tester for fiber: easily runs to $5000 for a cheap one and top-end testers can be 10x as much.